# Как закруглить блок с изображением?

Tags: html, css

есть такой кусок макета
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как закруглить блок с изображением, чтобы получилось как на картинке.

```css
.feedback__person {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 191px;
  height: 69px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background: #e8e7e7;
}

.feedback__person .img-wrapper {
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.feedback__person .img-wrapper .person-img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.feedback__person .text-wrap {
  width: 90px;
  height: 54px;
}

.feedback__person .text-wrap .feedback__comment {
  color: #515151;
  font-family: Arial, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.feedback__person .text-wrap .feedback__author {
  color: #828282;
  font-family: Arial, serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback__person">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://imgur.com/a/0Jb6py1" alt="" class="person-img">
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrap">
    <div class="feedback__comment">
      I was in Poznan once. The architecture is really awesome.
    </div>
    <div class="feedback__author">
      Joe Wisdom, architect
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо картинку сделать как фоновое изображение у `.img-wrapper` и `border-radius: 50%` а у основного блока скруглить только левый край

```
.img-wrapper {
    background-image: url(https://imgur.com/a/0Jb6py1);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.feedback__person {
    border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Надо картинку сделать как фоновое изображение у .img-wrapper и border-radius: 50% а у основного блока скруглить только левый край

Только задавать надо в пикселях(любое значение которое будет больше высоты половины блока), иначе углы получаются овальными, а не круглыми